Trouble calculating currents in a circuit with Supermesh and dependent voltage source
I stuck with this question : We got current meshes: 
I attempted to create a supermesh for I2 and I3 , and a separate regular mesh for I4 To complete the matrix, I added two additional KCL equations: I1=2A and I3=I2+3. Additionally, we know that the value of Vb is 2 the current through the R5 resistor. Unfortunately, the currents I calculated turned out to be incorrect. I suspect there might be an error in my supermesh formulation or in the value of Vb within the meshes.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
(The final answers are : I1=2A , I2=74/47A , I3=-67/47A , I4=101/188A)

Why didn't you simplify first? And, more importantly, you didn't state what you were trying to solve. That is needed. Anyway, the simplifications are the shorting out of R6 and R7. The reason you can short them out because a resistor that is placed exclusively in series with a current source has no effect on the rest of the circuit so, do this first then, use whatever method you choose to solve for whatever you want to solve for: -

My changes are in orange. Aldo, you say you have a dependent source but I can't seem to see what it's dependent on.

Hi, thank you for your answer!
The current dependent voltage source is located at the bottom of the circuit, and its voltage depends on the current through the R5 resistor.resistor. My goal is to determine the current for each mesh in the circuit.
Thank you for your help!
